# A question about Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

**1-** Put **Book1.xlsx** file to the **Solution Explorer** by following **Add > Existing Item**

**2-** Set properties of **Book1.xlsx** in the **Solution Explorer** like following ;

*Build Action:* Content

*Copy to Output Directory:* Copy Always

**3-** Run this project and see if **Book1.xlsx** file is copied to the the **Debug** folder

**4-** Close this project.

**5-** Open **Book1.xlsx** file manually by finding it in the **Debug** folder. Keep **Book1.xlsx** file open.

**6-** Run this project again and see the following error;

> Could not copy
>   "C:\Users\onsuz\OneDrive\Desktop\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\Book1.xlsx"
>   to "bin\Debug\Book1.xlsx". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process
>   cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Book1.xlsx' because it is being used
>   by another process.

As you can see if a curious person opens **Book1.xlsx** file manually before my application start then my application crashes.

Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your application crashing, this is your application failing to compile as it cannot overwrite this file.  This particular issue will not happen at runtime as you will be deploying a pre-compiled version of your code.